# View visibility do not shows after being invisible

Tags: android, android-view

I have two views one is a button and the other is `LinearLayout`.

When i set `View.GONE` and then to `View.VISIBLE` the view wont get visible again.
This mechanism was working in the past.

```
android:id="@+id/selector_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_white_1"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/actions_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    layout="@layout/wait_request_accept_panel"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/selector_controls"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/selector_controls"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/selector_controls">
```

Now... what i want is to toggle is the elements inside `wait_request_accept_panel` this is the layout file, I want to toggle elements inside it..

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wait_container"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_white_1">

    <!-- Other view elements -->

</RelativeLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    style="@style/H18b"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_white_1"
    android:text="@string/str_accept"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

As you can se here there is two elements basically a `wait_container` which shows up when user is waiting, and a Button `btnAccept` it only change state once: one in the original state which is, **wait_container** is GONE and button `Button` which is visible at first time. When I hit `btnAccept`the btn changes to **GONE** and the wait container changes to **VISIBLE**
Here is the programatic impementation:

```
switch (req.getType()) {
        case REQ: // this is the initial flow
            waitContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            acceptBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case ACCEPT: // after hit the accept btn it toggles the two views
            acceptBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            waitContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
```

### Init details

```
waitContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wait_container);
acceptBtn     = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
cancelBtn     = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
```

Something to take in count is the fact the `waitContainer` and `acceptBtn` are included, they came from another xml file, I did that because I wanted to reuse code, but in this moment that's not so important since the current screen is the only that uses the `wait_request_accept_panel.xml` file.

## SOLUTION

The view were always there, but it's alpha channel was modified by an animation when the fragment was starting, I sent by mistake the `viewContainer` as a parameter to the animation method which i turns animates its alpha channel.

Comment: post your view initialization code

Comment: your req.getType() is probably always req

Comment: @propoLis I ran a test over what your said and the `req` object changes it's state from `REQ` to `ACCEPT`, so I discard that possibility. Also, I checked the  it the views (acceptBtn, waitContainer) to not being modified in any other place in the fragment.

Comment: @SkyAlligator check the update up for the init details.

Comment: The view were always there, but it's alpha channel was modified by an animation when the fragment was starting, I sent by mistake the `viewContainer` as a parameter to the animation method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [**`getVisibility ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility()).

> Returns the visibility status for this view.

```
 if(waitContainer.getVisibility()== View.GONE)
    {
      acceptBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      waitContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that. But no results. Although I just set its initial state for `waitContainer` as `VISIBLE` and `acceptBtn` as `GONE` and I notice that the `waitContainer` is still `GONE`, so something wierd is happening here.

Comment: I also checked the value for `waitContainer` after set to `VISIBLE` and it remains invisible.

Comment: The answer is the alpha channel of the view was modified by an animation at the beginning when the fragment starts. So the `waitContainer` was always there, but invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **visibility** of view after that apply **ViSIBLE/GONE** have look

```
if(waitContainer.getVisibility()== View.GONE)
    {
      waitContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
     waitContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion, but triggered from a third button. I did `acceptBtn.setVisibility(acceptBtn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);` and it works but something else is preventing the wait container for being visible after pass thru the `ACCEPT` state, Im still researching....